# Regex with escaped less-than and greater-than around e-mail address?

Tags: regex, email, notepad++

In Notepad++, I am looking to do a regex that replaces this:

```
Joe Schmoe <joe.schmoe@gmail.com>
```

with

```
joe.schmoe@gmail.com
```

I would've thought that:

```
^(.*) \<(.*?)\>$
```

would've put the required value into "`\2`".  However, Notepad++ reports that it finds no matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from `\<` and `\>` than stand for word boundary. Do not escape these characters if you want to match `<` and `>`.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?<(.+?)>`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
.+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
<               # literally
(.+?)           # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
>               # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

**Be aware that will not work for email like `"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com`**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to match your whole line of text:

```
.*<([.\w]+@\w+\.\w+)>
```

Then you can replace with `\1`, containing your email only. Make sure to have "Regular Expression" option checked.

**Regex Explanation**:

- `.*`: any sequence of characters
- `<`: open angular parenthesis
- `([.\w]+@\w+\.\w+)`: Group containing the email

  - `[\.\w]+`: email name
  - `@`: @
  - `\w+(?:\.\w+)`: the domain
- `>`: closed angular parenthesis

Check the regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/oyWPWK/1).

Note: If you need a more complex email pattern matching, you can look [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression).

Comment: `[.\w]+` is not enough for an email. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Comment: This is the reason why there's a note at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Hi there, in your pattern you don't have to escape the dot in the character class and you can omit the non capture group in the last part `.*<([.\w]+@\w+\.\w+)>`  (or repeat it 1 or more times as the group by itself this way has no purpose)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, didn't know about the dot escape inside the character class.